# Add Users with Active Directory Description Attribute to a group containing the Department Attribute

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I try to add every User of an AD with a special description to a group wich contains the Department Attribute (**up to 3 digits**) as a suffix.

**For Example**

> A User "Sam Test" has the Description "Boss" and the Department "123".
>   He should be added to Testgroup_123.

**My Goal**

Write a Script to add the Users to their associated Testgroup_???.

There can only be one Boss(User) in a Testgroup_???.

For testing reasons I only try to output the name.

**This is my Code so far:**

```
 import-module ActiveDirectory
    $user = 
    Get-ADUser -filter {(description -like "Boss") -or 
                        (description -like "boss") -or 
                        (description -like "Assistant")} -searchbase "OU=TestOU,DC=TE,DC=ADS" -Properties Enabled, description, sAMAccountName, Department | select Department | Foreach {Write-Host "Testgroup_$user<-empty?"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your right, try this code:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description,Department

    foreach ($user in $Users)
    {

        if ($user.Description -match "Boss|Assistant") 
        {

        $Dep = $User.Department

        if (-not(Get-ADGroup "Testgroup_$Dep")) 

            {
            New-ADGroup -Path "OU=TestOU,DC=TE,DC=ADS" -Name "Testgroup_$Dep" -GroupScope Global
            }

        else
            {
                $GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Testgroup_$Dep" | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
                if ($User.SamAccountName -notin $GroupMembers)
                {
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Testgroup_$Dep" -Members $User
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. First it gets all the users
2. Check for each user for description match of "Boss" or "Assistant"
3. Get the department attribute for the user (just for example 666)
4. Check if Group name "Testgroup_666" Exist, if not Create new one in the path you defined
5. Check if the user is not already a member of this group, if not add add the user to the group

Comment: It is going in the right direction. But at 3. I just want the value of the Department. It should not be equal to "123" or anything else. Then the Groupname should get the attribute.

Comment: Updated my answer, check it now